# Create Python list from key in dict

Tags: python

If I have a dict in Python like the following:

```
d = {'hello': [{a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:4, b:5, c:6},{a:7, b:8, c:9}]}
```

I'd like to create an array that will give me all the values of "b".  Short of iterating over the array for key "hello", is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You have to iterate over it.

Answer (score 4):

Use a list comprehension:

```
b_list = [subdict[b] for subdict in d['hello']]
```

Iterate over all the sub-dictionaries in the value stored by `hello` and access the value stored by the key `b`.